# Regular Expression Matches

Tags: regex

```
([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/?([^.\/]+)[\.php|\.html]
```

For this expression, why does the string 'people' match and 'person' doesn't?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're asking?

Comment: I guess he means "Why the string 'people' matches and 'person' doesn't".

Comment: ... Sorry, what? Please try a full sentence, for a start. >.<

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, try to be a little more clear in your questions. If you need help with English, you can also put that in your question (encouraging others who can edit to help you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because what you've got at the end in square brackets should be in parentheses. 'people' matches it up to the 'l' in the square brackets, but 'person' has no letter in the square brackets.

and if you don't want to force a match with either .php or .html, you should follow that with a question mark.

here is a possible revised regex: `([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?([^.\/]+)(.php|.html)?`

```
>>> p='([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/?([^.\/]+)(\.php|\.html)?'
>>> p=re.compile(p)
>>> p.match('person')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9bac0c0>
>>> p.match('people')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9bac2f0>
>>> p.match('people').group()
'people'
>>> p.match('person').group()
'person'
```

Use the match.group() function, or its equivalent in your favorite language, to see what part of a regex is actually matching. it can be very illuminating.

---

for the revised question in the comments:

```
>>> p=re.compile('([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)(|\.html|\.php)$')
>>> p.match('ddd').group()
'ddd'
>>> p.match('ddd.html').group()
'ddd.html'
>>> p.match('ddd.jpeg').group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Hi. thanks.I actually want to make both 'people' and 'person' match.

Comment: they both do in the regex as modified above.

Comment: what I want to do is making url redirect to page.php. ddd should redirect, ddd.php should redirect, ddd.html should redirect, but ddd.jpeg shoud not, ddd.css should not, and so on. thanks

Comment: it seems the ddd.jpeg still match when I use 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html' to test it

Comment: that page appears to be buggy.